# how to write a query in firestore to update data according to id in the inner array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to access the id which a map inside an array which inside another array?
I have attached firestore structure here
[db structure in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etaP1.png)

Comment: You can use ```Products.0.sub_products.0.city```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my code.. im using two where conditions here as you can see, you have to go to the refrence of that collection and add .where("fieldnameinfirestore", "yourvalue")..

```
     private void GetCityListsnames() {

    db.collection("citylist").document("city").
            collection(uservolcity).whereEqualTo("complete","false").
       whereEqualTo("takebyvol","false")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            mlistsproper.add(new VolListProperDataModel(document.getId(),document.getString("listname"),
                                    document.getString("sendinguserphone"),
                                    document.getString("sendingusername"),
                                    document.getString("deliveryaddress"),uservolcity));

                        }
                        if(mlistsproper.size() == 0){
                            nolist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        GetAccptListsnames();

                    } else {
                        Log.d("Errorgeetingaddres", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Make sure you have added delivery address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you success listner of firestore request you can get the array like this!

```
List<String> group = (List<String>) document.get("arrayfieldname");
```

Comment: i need to know how to use where() to update particular array eg:collection.where("id","==",123).update({name:xyz})

Comment: as the answer is bit long let me post a answer instead of comment.